# Pass onSaved to a TextFormField widget?

Tags: flutter

In order to create a reusable widget that returns a TextFormField, is there a way to pass the field that needs to be updated when onSaved is called?

Consider the following map:

```
  Map myMap = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
  }
```

and a simple build method:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTile(myMap.a);
  }
```

and my common widget with specific decoration (not shown) that is used in many locations

```
  Widget _buildTile(int fieldIn) {
    return TextFormField(
      onSaved: (value) => print('Tile onSaved: $value'),  //how to update myMap.a?
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-primitives in dart are passed by reference, this includes maps. So you can do:

```
Widget _buildTile(Map map, dynamic key) {
    return TextFormField(
      onSaved: (value) => map[key] = value,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas.  That satisfies the example that I provided, but what if it were an object instead of a Map?  Then how would I access the key?
`main() {
  Obj myObj = Obj(a: 1, b: 2,);
  doPrint(myObj, 'a');
}

doPrint(Obj o, String key) {
  print(o);
  print(o[key]);
}

class Obj {
  Obj({
    this.a,
    this.b,
  });
  int a;
  int b;
}`

Comment: Are you coming from Javascript? You might still mean a `Map`. A `Map<dynamic>` can have keys of any type. Note the key parameter is dynamic in the example I gave.

Comment: that doesn't work.  Cut and paste the code from my previous comment into dartpad.

Comment: No, it won't work for class members, only a map. The alternative (and it's probably a better practice) is to make `onSaved` a parameter of your custom widget which is passed down to `TextFormField`.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of (as shown in the title of this issue).  :(
I was hoping for a more elegant solution.  That looks really ugly when coded.
Thanks again for your help.  I really appreciate your replies.  :)

Answer (score 0):

try:
create a parameter like

```
final FormFieldSetter<String> onSaved;
```

font: [example](https://hashnode.com/post/create-reusable-password-field-in-flutter-with-preview-check-cjqmlpo6z005evhs2y5443bs6)